# How to understand the difference between 2 lists, provided that the names in the other 2 lists are equal

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python, I have two excel files, each of them is for one month. I wanted to come and use the special code of my employees to subtract their one month's salary from their one month's salary and get the difference. I tried a lot, but I couldn't find a way. I would be grateful if you could simulate this topic on these lists for me so that I can follow your example

```
salary_month_1 = [232, 432]
employee_list_month_1 = ['elly', 'john']

employee_list_month_2 = ['elly', 'john']
salary_month_2 = [540, 655]

# output I need : "elly (540 - 232) = 308", "john (655 - 432) = 223"
```

Comment: You have two excel files but your data is in four lists and not two DataFrames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have the data in lists like you shown in the question and not in Pandas df. If so, I think this would work. Provided the length of employees list and salary lists are same.

```
    salary_month_1 = [232, 432]
    employee_list_month_1 = ['elly', 'john']

    employee_list_month_2 = ['elly', 'john']
    salary_month_2 = [540, 655]

    emp_list = set(employee_list_month_1) & set(employee_list_month_2)
    emp_salary = {}
    for index, emp in enumerate(emp_list):
        salary1 = salary_month_1[index]
        salary2 = salary_month_2[index]
        emp_salary[emp] = salary2 - salary1
    
    print(emp_salary)
```

Comment: It's true, but I want to make a condition before that, only if the names were in this list and there was one in that list, only reduce the rights of one of the names.

Comment: What I gave you above should be a good starting point I hope.